# Bijection beteween maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

We know that if $R$ and $I$ an ideal of $R$, then there is a bijection between the prime ideals of $R$ containing $I$ and the prime ideals of $R/I$. It is given by $P\mapsto P/I$. Is it true that this map gives a bijection between the maximal ideals of $R$ containing $I$ and the maximal ideals of $R/I$ ?

Comment: I know that if $M/I$ is a maximal ideal of $R/I$ then, $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. But is the converse true ?

Comment: Do you mean maximal/prime ideals of $R$ *which contain $I$*?

Comment: Yes. I mean maximal ideals containing $I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converse is indeed true. If $I \subset M \subset R$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, then $R/I/M/I \cong R/M$ by the third isomorphism theorem for rings, so $M/I$ is a maximal ideal of $R/I$. Note that the same argument shows that prime ideals in $R$ containing $I$ project to prime ideals in the quotient $R/I$.